# Zipping nested lists in Python

Tags: python

Say I have the following two lists/numpy arrays:

```
List1 = [[1,2,3,4], [10,11,12], ...]
List2 = [[-1,-2-3,-4], [-10,-11,-12], ...]
```

I would like to obtain a list that holds the zipping of the nested lists above:

```
Result = [[(1,-1), (2,-2), (3,-3), (4,-4)], [(10,-10), (11, -11), (12,-12)], ...]
```

Is there a way to do this with a one-liner (and in a Pythonic way)?

Comment: The following answer supports arbitrarily deep nested lists, not sure whether or not that is a requirement here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12630570/505154

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
l1 = [[1,2,3,4], [10,11,12]]
l2 = [[-1,-2,-3,-4], [-10,-11,-12]]

print [zip(a,b) for a,b in zip(l1,l2)]
```

```
[[(1, -1), (2, -2), (3, -3), (4, -4)], [(10, -10), (11, -11), (12, -12)]]
```

Comment: Was just about to hit post on that same answer! gaw! +1. Even with the a,b names.

Comment: You could also suggest `itertools.izip` for the original lists in case they are huge. It would save on creating a big temp zip list. But only if the source lists would be large

Comment: @jdi And only in 2.x - in 3.x `zip()` produces generators, not lists, anyway.

Comment: @Lattyware: So far I have only assumed people are using py3 if they tag it or specifically mention it. But good info all the same!