# How to write a function to zip two nested lists?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

My ultimate goal is a function combining two nested lists, like this:

```
def tuples_maker(l1, l2):

    
    return sample_data
```

I know that I can use zip, but I don't know how to utilize "for" loop. I got stuck at first step then I cannot continue....

for example,

```
l1 = [[1,2,3,4], [10,11,12]]
l2 = [[-1,-2,-3,-4], [-10,-11,-12]]
```

I want something like this:

```
[[(1, -1), (2, -2), (3, -3), (4, -4)], [(10, -10), (11, -11), (12, -12)]]
```

On stack overflow I actually found a solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13675517/12159353

```
print(list(zip(a,b) for a,b in zip(l1,l2)))
```

but it generates a iteration not a list:

```
[<zip object at 0x000002286F965208>, <zip object at 0x000002286F965AC8>]
```

so I try not to use list comprehension:

```
for a,b in zip(l1,l2):        
    c=list(zip(a,b))
print(c)
```

it is overlapped:

```
[(10, -10), (11, -11), (12, -12)]
```

I know this's not right but I still make a try:

```
for a,b in zip(l1,l2):        
    c=list(zip(a,b))
    print(c)
```

Now it seems right, but not a list:

```
[(1, -1), (2, -2), (3, -3), (4, -4)]
[(10, -10), (11, -11), (12, -12)]
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change first `zip` to `list`  or leave them as tuple: `list(zip(l1,l2))` for list of tuple or `list(list(x) for x in zip(l1,l2))` for list of lists. Follow the same for nested list in your example data

Comment: You almost did it with the list comprehension. Just misplaced the closing brace of `list`. `result = [ list(zip(a, b)) for a, b in zip(l1, l2) ]`, or `result = [ list(zip(*x)) for x in zip(l1, l2) ]`.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating the `zip` object yields a tuple of values, so you need to explicitly pass it to a `list` constructor if you want to create list out of those values

```py
def combine_lists(l1,l2):
    return list([list(y) for y in zip(*x)] for x in zip(l1,l2))
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
print(combine_lists(l1,l2))
#output
[[[1, -1], [2, -2], [3, -3], [4, -4]], [[10, -10], [11, -11], [12, -12]]]
```

**UPDATE:**

To get innermost pairs as tuple, just remove the innermost list constructor:

```py
def combine_lists(l1,l2):
    return list([y for y in zip(*x)] for x in zip(l1,l2))
    
print(combine_lists(l1,l2))
#prints
[[(1, -1), (2, -2), (3, -3), (4, -4)], [(10, -10), (11, -11), (12, -12)]]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Sorry to say this but it is required that it is tuple inside. Do you mind giving more ideas?

Comment: @resssslll Look at the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

In a list comprehension you can zip each sub-list separately like this:

```
l1 = [[1,2,3,4], [10,11,12]]
l2 = [[-1,-2,-3,-4], [-10,-11,-12]]

def sub_zip(l1, l2):
    return [list(zip(l1[i], l2[i])) for i in range(len(l1))]

sub_zip(l1, l2)
```

Output:

```
[[(1, -1), (2, -2), (3, -3), (4, -4)], [(10, -10), (11, -11), (12, -12)]]
```